# Let g: $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ be given by: $g(x,y) = (x+y, x-y)$

Tags: functions, proof-writing

**1) Find the Image of g.**

I had really no idea on how to prove this using some sort of concrete mathematical argument, so I brute-forced a bunch of values and plotted them onto a graph and made a observation. From the graph it seems like the image of the function seems to be $f(x_1, x_2)$, $x_1$ is even, and $x_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**2) Is the function a bijection?**

From the image, its easy to tell the function is not a bijection because it is not surjection.

Counter-example: $∄  x_1, x_2$ such that $f(x_1, x_2) = (2,1)$.

Again, I have no clue how to write a concrete proof for this. If someone could help that would be amazing.

[image]

Comment: There are many points in this image where $x_1$ is not even, such as $(1,1)$. What you're seeing is that if $(x_1,x_2)$ is in the image then $x_1$ and $x_2$ have the same parity. In terms of determining the image, what happens if you try to solve $(x+y,x-y) = (x_1,x_2)$ for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: No idea what you mean in the sentence starting with “the image of the function seems to be…” What is $f?$ What does it mean to say  “$f(x_1,x_2), x_1$ is even and $x_2\in\mathbb Z?$”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To show $g$ is not a bijection:** as you intuited, we can show $g$ is not surjective. Suppose $g(x,y)=(1,0)$. Then for some $x,y\in\Bbb Z$, $x+y=1$ and $x-y=0$. The latter implies $x=y$, so $x+y=2x=1$, which is impossible since $x\in\Bbb Z$.

**Finding the image of $g$:** first you have to translate the visual pattern you found into set notation. It looks like the image consists of all $(x,y)$ such that, when $y$ is even, $x$ is even, and, when $y$ is odd, $x$ is odd. In other words,
$$\operatorname{im}(g)=\{(2x,2y):x,y\in\Bbb Z\}\cup\{(2x+1,2y+1):x,y\in\Bbb Z\}.$$
Once you've written this, you can directly prove it. To prove $A=B$, you must show that $p\in A\implies p\in B$ and $p\in B\implies p\in A$. In this case, $A=\operatorname{im}(g)$ and $B=\{(2x,2y),(2x+1,2y+1):x,y\in\Bbb Z\}$.

- Suppose $p\in A$. Then we can write $p=g(x,y)$ for some $x,y\in\Bbb Z$. That means $p=(x+y,x-y)$. Consider the two possible cases here: either $x$ and $y$ have the same parity, or they have different parities. Show that, in either case, $(x+y,x-y)$ is in $B$.
- Suppose $p\in B$. There are two cases. I will consider the first, and you can fill in the rest. If $p=(2x,2y)$ for some $x,y\in\Bbb Z$, then $p=g(x,x)+g(y,-y)=g(x+y,x-y)\in\operatorname{im}(g)$.